# Detached entity causes tracking exceptions when invoking UserManager.AddToRoleAsync()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, identity

I'm trying to assign an IdentityRole to an IdentityUser entity, but I get the following exception:

> InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'User' cannot
>   be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'}
>   is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure
>   that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

In my method, I select the User object and sets State to Detached. I've also tried using AsNoTracking, but still the same error.

**Code**:

```
public async Task<IdentityResult> AssignRole(int userId, string roleName)
{
    IUser usr = await this.DBContext.Context.IdentityUsers.FirstOrDefaultAsync(r => r.Id.Equals(userId));

    this.DBContext.Context.Detach(usr);

    var result = await _user.AddToRoleAsync((User)usr, roleName);

    return result;
}
```

**DBContext, Detach**:

```
public void Detach(ILCAssetsBase entity)
{
    this.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
}
```

Comment: I could write a custom method that inserts a row in the table directly without using UserManager, but I would like to use the recommended implementation

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the User entity was processed by different DbContext.

This works:

```
public async Task<IdentityResult> AssignRole(int userId, string roleName)
{
    User usr = await _user.FindByIdAsync(userId.ToString());
    var result = await _user.AddToRoleAsync(usr, roleName);

    return result;
}
```